# open popover from typeahead list

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a [typeahead textfield from bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#typeahead). What I want to do is: When you click on an item from typeahead list they open a popover and it will be placed on the textfield. Is this possible?

I already have an item that have `onclick="alert(000)" rel="popover"`. If I click on it the alertbox will open, so it can do something. But the popover doesnt work. Is it even possible to open a popover from typeahead?

Comment: My attempt failed: http://jsfiddle.net/8NRyr/10 
I had hoped that changing $.fn.typeahead.defaults and `i.find('a').html(that.highlighter(item))` from render would be enough. But that is not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the `updater` option is not documented, you can use it to do something when an item is selected : [Demo (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/ExKsC/)

```js
$('#myTypeahead').typeahead({
    source: source,
    updater: function(item) {
        // Do something here, `item` is the selected item
        return item;
    }
});
```

Comment: As far as i understand the question Chanckjh would like to have a popover for each match in the menu. For exmample typing te returns 2 matching entries. Each of this entries should have a popover.
@Chanckjh: Could you clarify it for us? Thanks

Comment: Indeed, I don't know how to properly do that without extending the plugin. I'll leave the answer just in case.

Comment: Wow this is exactly what i wanted to do! When you click on an item a popover will be placed on the textfield! Now I'm gonna try to put a form in the popover! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Sherbrow Hi, I've got a little problem. I'm trying to select a specicic item from the list and then open the popover. How can I select a specific item?

Comment: @Chanckjh You should put the `Do something here` in another function, which you would call both in the `updater` function and after setting manually your specific item. Search for similar questions on stackoverflow before asking that in another question.