# typeahead.js - customize dropdown suggestions with pop up

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead.js

I am trying to figure out how to customize the suggestion for `typeahead.js`. Basically i want to search for a doctor id contained within a `JSON` file and provide a typeahead `dropdown` of relevant doctor ids and on `mouseover` event display more details about the doctor.

here is my sample for typeahead.

```
 DoctorIdTypeahead.typeahead({
                 highlight: true
             }, {
                 name: 'Doctor_ID',
                 displayKey: 'Doctor_ID',
                 source: ids.ttAdapter(),
                 templates: {
                     empty: [
                            '<div class="empty-message">',
                            'No match',
                            '</div>'
                            ].join('\n'),
                     suggestion: function (data) {
                         return '<p class="tooltip">' + data.Doctor_ID + '</p>' +
                         '<div class="panel panel-default">' +
                            '<div class="panel-footer">' +
                                '<p>Name:' + data.Doctor_Name + '</p>' +
                                '<p>Practice Number:' + data.Practice_Number + '</p>' +
                                '<p>Qualifications:' + data.Qualifications + '</p>' +
                                '<p>Specilisation:' + data.Specialisation + '</p>' +
                            '</div>' +
                          '</div>';

                     }
                 }
             });
```

So as you can see currently next to each ID i am displaying a full list of doc details.
So once again instead I wanted to find to display doc details on `mouseover` event of doc id.

I tried using jbox to display a tooltip and put all my content there:

```
        $(function () {
        $('.tooltip').on('mouseover', function () {
            $('.tooltip').jBox('Tooltip', { content: 'great stuff' });
        });
    });
```

However i am not getting any results.

How can i make this work

So i checked the a similar question but for a bootstrap typeahead. [open popover from typeahead list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13084521/open-popover-from-typeahead-list)

However, in this scenario the popup appears after a list item had been clicked. And i see how this is possible for typeahead.js - > can be implemented in the itemselectedhandler. However, it seems to defeat the purpose as the item has already been selected and the user is not aware of other details corresponding to the selected id.

I have also checked the supported typeahead.js event handlers: **typeahead:cursorchanged**
I am going to try out this event and see if the it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So from what i have discovered the typeahead:cursorchanged event can actually work in this scenario. However, it is triggered by key press and not by mouseover therefore this is a partial success.

```
                 var employeeIdItemCursorChanged = function (eventObject, suggestionObject, suggestionDataset) {

                 //Code to run Popup
             };

employeeIdTypeahead.on('typeahead:cursorchanged', employeeIdItemCursorChanged);
```