# Show popover when hovering over typeahead drop-down suggestions

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, autocomplete, typeahead, bootstrap-popover

I want to show a `bootstrap popover` when hovering over the `typeahead autocomplete drop-down` suggestions. I referred this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13084521/open-popover-from-typeahead-list).

```js
$('#myTypeahead').typeahead({
        source: source,
        updater: function(item) {
            $('#myTypeahead').popover({content: item}).popover('show');
            return item;
        }
    });
```

But here popover is showing only after selecting the drop-down menu. I want to show popover when hovering the menu not selecting.

Comment: Post "your" code so we can see how you did it

Comment: Improved content formatting and added relevant tags